# reactjs dashboards vs BI reporting tools || which one has the edge?

Tags: reactjs, powerbi, reporting

I see react also has support for the dashboard programming libraries.. will it be used as a replacement for bi report tools?

Need to know when we can go for react dashboard libraries.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to mix two completely different tools here. BI report tools are used by business directly. I mean, there is a platform where they can go and work with the tool. Charting libraries in Javascript is used when you are developing a custom report inside a web application. So, unless the business is going to use your custom web app for reporting, there is no need of javascript libraries.